# Exporting to Excel with iReport/Jasper fails, calling from Java

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I am new to iReport 3.7.4 with Java, I get errors when I export my report to Excel, below is the complete code.
I am using Excel 2016.

What I get when I try my code is, the Excel file is downloaded,
but when I open the file it shows me the error that data is not in correct format and I receive errors on the console.
The images below is the output of my excel sheet.

```
Connection con = null;

try {

Dao dao = new Dao();
List parm = new ArrayList();
con = adminSession.con;
String progId = request.getParameter("progId");
String termId = request.getParameter("term");

String testId=" 303";
HashMap map = new HashMap();
//  map.put("P_PROG_ID", progId);
map.put("P_TERM_ID", termId);
//map.put("sectionId", sectionId);
// map.put("section", section);
String rootFolder = null;
String ServletPath = request.getServletPath();
String ServletName = ServletPath.substring(1);
String ServletPathReal = application.getRealPath(ServletPath);
String sep = "";
String ReportPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/Images/");
if (ServletPathReal.indexOf("\\") > 0) {
    sep = "\\";
} else {
    sep = "/";
}

OutputStream stream = null;
ReportPath = ServletPathReal.substring(0, ServletPathReal.lastIndexOf(sep));
String reportTitle = request.getParameter("title");
if (reportTitle != null && reportTitle.length() > 0) {
    reportTitle = reportTitle.toUpperCase();
}
FileInputStream input = null;

JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
String reportName = "CandidatesUnpaidChallan";
String reportPath = java.io.File.separatorChar + "";
String subPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
subPath = subPath + reportPath + "reports" + reportPath;
String path = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports");
String name = "CandidatesUnpaidChallan.jrxml";
String totalPath = path + File.separator + name;
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(totalPath);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,map,  con);

String filename = path + File.separator + "CandidatesUnpaidChallan";//.xlsx";
// String excelOutput = filename + "_" + dateAppend + ".xlsx";
  java.util.Date dNow = new java.util.Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
String dateAppend = ft.format(dNow);
String excelOutput = filename;// + "_" + dateAppend + ".xlsx";
//ByteArrayOutputStream outputByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 /* JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,outputByteArray );//outputByteArray);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.exportReport();*/
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1", "pageHeader");
// Remove the column headers except the first one
    jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2", "columnHeader");

//  Remove the pageFooter from all the pages
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2", "pageFooter");
//  set the JXL parameters to generate Excel report
JExcelApiExporter jExcelApiExporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER,Boolean.TRUE);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,Boolean.FALSE);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,Boolean.TRUE);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OFFSET_X,0);
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OFFSET_Y,0 );
jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, excelOutput);
//jExcelApiExporter.exportReport(jasperPrint, filename);
// jExcelApiExporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,filename);
jExcelApiExporter.exportReport();

File    file = new File(filename+".xlsx");
// SET THE MIME TYPE.
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
// set content dispostion to attachment in with file name.
// case the open/save dialog needs to appear.
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+reportName+".xlsx");    
//response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + reportName + "_" + dateAppend + ".xlsx\"");
input = new FileInputStream(file);
int readBytes = 0;
BufferedInputStream  buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
stream = response.getOutputStream();
while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
    stream.write(readBytes);
}
stream.flush();
input.close();
stream.close();

} catch (Exception oops) {
System.out.println(oops);
con = null;
throw new Exception("Error occured while showing Evaluations~" + oops.toString());
} finally {
con = null;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The error on the console is:

```
020 10:57:40.569 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MAJUKHI] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.Admin.AdminProcessCandidateUnpaidChallans_jsp._jspService(AdminProcessCandidateUnpaidChallans_jsp.java:546)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

```
Here is my jrxmlcode containing the query:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="CandidatesUnpaidChallan" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="822" leftMargin="10" rightMargin="10" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="P_TERM_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT T.TERM_NME, ' '||P.PROG_ABBREV PROG_ABBREV,S.FORM_NBR,' '||C.FIRST_NME||' '||C.MIDDLE_NME||' '||C.LAST_NME NME,C.L_PHONE1_NBR,' '||C.P_ADDRESS_TXT P_ADDRESS_TXT,' '||C.P_EMAIL_TXT P_EMAIL_TXT,FCN.INSTALLMENT_DUE_DTE
    FROM MAJUMSKHI.TERM T, MAJUMSKHI.CANDIDATE C,MAJUMSKHI.SELECTION S,MAJUMSKHI.FEE_CHALLAN_NEW FCN,MAJUMSKHI.FEE_CANDIDATE FC,MAJUMSKHI.BATCH B,MAJUMSKHI.TERM_PROGRAM TP,MAJUMSKHI.PROGRAM P
    WHERE C.CAND_ID=S.CAND_ID
    AND C.TERM_ID = T.TERM_ID
    AND S.CAND_ID=FCN.CAND_ID
    AND FCN.FEE_CHALLAN_NEW_ID=FC.FEE_CHALLAN_NEW_ID
    AND S.BATCH_ID=B.BATCH_ID
    AND B.TERM_PROG_ID=TP.TERM_PROG_ID
    AND TP.PROG_ID=P.PROG_ID
    AND S.REG_NBR IS NULL
    AND FCN.PAID_DTE IS NULL
    AND FC.COUNT_NBR IS NOT NULL
    AND FC.DISCOUNTED_AMT>0
    AND C.TERM_ID=$P{P_TERM_ID}
    ORDER BY P.PROG_ABBREV,S.FORM_NBR]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="TERM_NME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="PROG_ABBREV" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="FORM_NBR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="L_PHONE1_NBR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="P_ADDRESS_TXT" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="P_EMAIL_TXT" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="INSTALLMENT_DUE_DTE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
        <variable name="TCHR_NME_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <variable name="COURSE_NME_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <variable name="Sr#" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Sr#}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <title>
            <band height="10" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band height="96">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="822" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Mohammad Ali Jinnah University Karachi]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="89" width="822" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="822" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Candidates Unpaid Challan]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="358" y="57" width="45" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Term:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="405" y="57" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TERM_NME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="26" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Sr#]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="82" y="0" width="67" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Admit Card No.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="149" y="0" width="154" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ Candidate Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="303" y="0" width="68" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Contact No.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="27" y="0" width="55" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ Program]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="371" y="0" width="229" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ Postal Adress]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="600" y="0" width="156" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ Email Adress]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="756" y="0" width="66" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Due Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="82" y="0" width="67" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{FORM_NBR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="149" y="0" width="154" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{NME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1" y="0" width="26" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{Sr#}+1]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="27" y="0" width="55" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{PROG_ABBREV}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="303" y="0" width="68" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{L_PHONE1_NBR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="371" y="0" width="229" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{P_ADDRESS_TXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="600" y="0" width="156" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{P_EMAIL_TXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="756" y="0" width="66" height="16"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.sql.Timestamp"><![CDATA[$F{INSTALLMENT_DUE_DTE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <pageFooter>
            <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="822" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <textField pattern="dd-MM-yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="7" width="100" height="10"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new 
      java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="766" y="6" width="38" height="10"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="804" y="6" width="18" height="10"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </pageFooter>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: Unreadable. Please format question for human readability.

Comment: Sayed, please take care for correct formatting when posting code. Please update your question to show the exact error message you receive.

Comment: sir when i export ireport to excel the excel file is generated and downloaded but when i open the excel file it show SQL query  instead of the required data .and it also give me the message of corrupted format that is  file format and extension of.xls don't match

Comment: please attach a screenshot [how to upload an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) of what you see

Comment: sir i have edit the post again

Comment: what about the error message, can you show it? add another screenshot or type the exact message text

Comment: this is the output of my report which shows in report

Comment: ok what I think is 1) output file is .xls but content is xlsx 2) the select query is not returning data or is not executed

Comment: where is your query, where is your connection defined? your code is not complete

Comment: i tried different extension of excel but required is .xls

Comment: Where in your code is `response` declared and set up? The error message looks like `response` has been used up before. And the data query doesn't seem to fetch any data, check with a simpler query if the db connection is valid and it is possible to request data.

Comment: thanks sir it work for me.thank you for your nice guidance.and sorry for my weak English. it was my first question in stack overflow